# Backbone + ol3: change map and firefox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers-3

I'm working with backbone.js and I have some dificulties to understand geolocation usage.

I'll try to explain this problem because the app is big and it has a lot of classes and it's dificult to understand:

We have an "A" view class, which switch the wiew betwen B and C class. Inside C class we can set another D or E, this last class will have our map in 1 atribute.

As you can see, we have this tree:

- A (View)
- >B
- >C (View)
- >>D
- >>E (View, with an atribbute which will stores an ol.map object.)

Ok, the problem begins when i need start this engine and pick geolocation since app request it. The sequence for E class is next:

Constructor: defines map, which it could be default (OSM) or transport (transport layer). Just a String to know what need the app when we create the object.

```
Render:  load the next code.
var view = new ol.View2D({
      // the view's initial state
      center: [0,0],
      zoom: 4
    });

    var marker = new ol.Overlay({
      element: document.getElementById('position'),
      positioning: ol.OverlayPositioning.CENTER_CENTER
    });


      if(this.model.get("map") == "default"){  

      console.log("carga default");  

      this.map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            preload: 4,
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        renderers: ol.RendererHints.createFromQueryData(),
        target: 'container',
        view: view
      });

          var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation();
          geolocation.bindTo('projection', this.map.getView());
          geolocation.setTracking(true);

          this.map.addOverlay(marker);
          marker.bindTo('position', geolocation);
      view.setCenter(ol.proj.transform([Number(longitude),Number(latitude)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
      view.setZoom(16);

      geolocation.on('change', function() {
        if(geolocation.getPosition() != null){
          console.log("cambia");
          console.log(geolocation.getPosition()[0]);
        }
      });
```

In theory, it works, but I have the next problems:
-In firefox doesn't work, but in chroimun browser works fine...
-If I "change" from OSM to transport map, i delete all data in the atribute and i load it again, even geolocation, but it drops the image that i use as point marker...
-If i return from transport map to OSM, i cant recover point image...

I don't know if this problem is related to async calls of ol3 and the render function of backbone.js, and i don't know if somebody here can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong...

Also, as you can see, in setCenter i user 2 vars (longitude and latitude), I would like to get if from geolocation tracking just the first time, how can I do it?

It's a hard question, but i really need some help of ol community here, please I'm lost at the moment.

Greetings and thank you in advance!

Comment: Somebody know how can I fix this?